# How to detect if default value is constant or expression in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, default-value

In Postgresql, how can I know default value is constant or expression?

Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS default_test  (
  id  serial primary key,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  father_name varchar(255) DEFAULT 'NULL', -- CONSTANT
  nn2 varchar(255) DEFAULT ('NULL'), -- CONSTANT
  nn3 varchar(255) DEFAULT (null), -- CONSTANT
  nn4 varchar(255) DEFAULT 'the default value', -- CONSTANT
  last_name varchar(255) NULL, -- CONSTANT
  dt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- EXPRESSION
  dt2 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2011-11-11 00:00:00', -- CONSTANT
  ts timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP /*ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*/,  -- EXPRESSION
  ts2 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2011-11-11 00:00:00',  -- CONSTANT
  date_col date DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '2 YEAR'), -- EXPRESSION
   i     INT DEFAULT -1, -- CONSTANT
   c     VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '', -- CONSTANT
   price DOUBLE precision DEFAULT 0.00, -- CONSTANT

   -- literal defaults
   i2 INT         DEFAULT 0, -- CONSTANT
   i3 INT         DEFAULT 3, -- CONSTANT
   pi_val FLOAT         DEFAULT 3.14, -- CONSTANT

   --
   f FLOAT       DEFAULT 3.14, -- CONSTANT
   d DATE        DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 YEAR'), -- EXPRESSION
   p POINT       DEFAULT (Point(0,0)), -- EXPRESSION
   j JSON        DEFAULT '{"a":"b"}'  -- CONSTANT


   
)
```

##### Similar part in MySQL

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Column with default expression have `DEFAULT_GENERATED` in Extra column in Information Schema

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Comment: In PostgreSQL, it is possible to see the default values by running this query - `select column_default from information_schema."columns" where table_name = 'default_test' and table_schema = 'test2'` You can get about what you want by checking for bracket characters, since any function or expression in PostgreSQL consists of these characters. but if we consider that functions like CURRENT_DATE do not have bracket symbols, then this will not be exactly the result you want. Also, I don't know if such a check exists in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can get that info in `adbin` field from `attdef` in the `pg_catalog`

If you have for example:

```sql
create table table1(
    w_def_expr text default current_user,
    w_def_cons text default 'hi',
    wo_def     text
);
```

You can get that info with this query:

```sql
select adrelid, tab.relname, attname, pg_get_expr(adbin, 0) expr, 
       split_part(substr(adbin,2),' ',1) expr_type
  from pg_attribute col
       inner join pg_class tab on col.attrelid = tab.oid
       inner join pg_attrdef def on col.attrelid = def.adrelid and col.attnum = def.adnum
  where tab.relname='table1';
```

Getting something like:

[image]

The way of getting info in `adbin` is not standar and can be change in the future.
I didn't find a way to do it better.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAB7nPqTOYbfGE1EiJ9ugg4U0545Jf7ULi1f1aMRg2BedtAEKcw%40mail.gmail.com) you can se an answer from 2017 saying that is not possible

Comment: It seems not exactly the same, neither exactly what you expected. `adbin` is `pg_node_tree` type. 'NULL' neither other constants are detected as CONST for varchar and float, but yes for timestamp, text and integer. I didn't try with all types.

Comment: The literal `'now'` for a timestamp is probably also a CONST but can evaluate to different values.